# How to debug or step-into Microsoft Forms Authentication source?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I've seen at least one question here that was similar to mine, but it wasn't answered, so here goes.

I want to step through the source for certain parts of the whole MS Forms auth library, specifically the Membership and Profile methods.

I have un-checked the "Enable just my code", I have the download symbols checked, etc.
(C#, VS2010)

However during debugging, it just steps over any of the Profile or Membership methods.